# How can I set Python symlink in MacOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, python, symlink

I am trying to set a symlink so that I can point the `python` command in Terminal to a new install of python3.

I last did this in Mojave, where one could disable csrutil and then run the following command before re-enabling:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

Now I am trying to do the same in MacOS Ventura 13.1, and I am met with the error feedback:

`ln: /usr/bin/python: Read-only file system`

What is this new roadblock that "MacOSimandius, destroyer of worlds" throws in my path?

And more importantly (please): **How do I set my symlink?** It must still be possible. This is still unix, is it not?

Comment: How did you install Python?

Comment: I have always done this using alias.

Comment: @Allan It's been a while. Quite sure that I used pip.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg I tried this first, and this also did not work. Perhaps these things together indicate the same problem? Or, perhaps, a bigger problem 8-(

Comment: If the mountain won't come to Mohammed, then why not change whatever script is calling `/usr/bin/python` (which presumably is written for python2)...?

Comment: @benwiggy That is the backup plan. Heckuvalotta scripts to change though :-P

Comment: Easy enough with a search and replace. If they're written for python2, they'll probably need changing anyway.

Comment: Probably not wise to rely upon `/usr/bin/python`, so you may need to bit the bullet and change your scripts so the path is not hard-coded.. If you need a system-wide Python version you can upgrade independently, why not just use `brew` to pull in the latest? Or if you need some finer control for a specific project, look into using `pyenv`, also available via `brew`. They can be set to supersede the macOS Python.

Comment: Man. I just want to code. :-|

Thanks for the advice. I am working through all of these ideas.

Comment: If you find the location of your python location, then you just modify your `PATH` variable so that it comes before the `/usr/bin` directory.  This ensures that when you run python, it's always going to "your" version first.  You can test with the command `which python` to see the one that gets called first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify `/usr/bin` any longer (at least not without disabling SSV). What you can do instead is

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

and then make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in `PATH`.

Comment: If you install python from python.org, rather than using Apple's version which comes with Xcode Tools, it will create `/usr/local/bin/python3` anyway.

Comment: @nohillside This one is a winner! In my case, the final symlink was ```python -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3```. Thanks very much.